# Is it possible to scale text on a canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas

I would like to draw text on a canvas using the [Canvas.drawText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) call for a game application, and later be able to scale it as if it was a bitmap object. I do not want to dynamically change its font size, but I want to scale it applying an affine transform.

Is it possible? I cannot find an adequate API call in the documentation.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) you can scale it and that apply the matrix tranformation to the canvas with [Canvas.concat(Matrix m)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#concat%28android.graphics.Matrix%29) . Do this before drawing the text onto the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Once it's on the Canvas, it's not a separate object that you can do anything to. What you can do is use the Canvas as an API for drawing to a bitmap:

1. Create a Bitmap.
2. Create a Canvas backed by that Bitmap.
3. Draw your text into the Canvas.
4. Hang on to your Bitmap and do whatever you want with it.

Comment: But to create a bitmap shouldn't I know the exact dimensions of the object?

Comment: @marzapower Yes, I assumed you knew the dimensions you needed.

Comment: @DarshanRivkaWhittle if I know the bitmap height and width then is there any way to auto adjust the text size within bitmap bound?
I have tried using static layout to draw two lines but if I increase the text size then it crops the text on the resulting image. Is there any way around?